Device or resource busy on AWS Lambda
Fresh deployed Python FastAPI application to AWS Lambda.
Python application uses ldap3 module to authorize user signing in against Windows Active directory (hosted on AWS Directory Services). However when attempting to login, exception is thrown:
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy

Full stack trace indicate not issue with ldap3, but in a higher level, when using native python sockets module, specifically using socket.getaddrinfo function.
Here is full stacktrace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app/library/ad.py", line 179, in get_ad_conn
    conn = ldap3.Connection(server, auto_bind = auto_bind, version = 3, authentication = ldap3.SASL, sasl_mechanism = ldap3.DIGEST_MD5, sasl_credentials = (None, username, password, None, 'ENCRYPT'), raise_exceptions=raise_exceptions)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 376, in __init__
    self._do_auto_bind()
  File "/opt/python/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 400, in _do_auto_bind
    self.open(read_server_info=False)
  File "/opt/python/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 58, in open
    BaseStrategy.open(self, reset_usage, read_server_info)
  File "/opt/python/ldap3/strategy/base.py", line 131, in open
    for candidate_address in self.connection.server.candidate_addresses():
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python/ldap3/core/server.py", line 622, in candidate_addresses
    for address in self.address_info:
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python/ldap3/core/server.py", line 258, in address_info
    addresses = socket.getaddrinfo(self.host, self.port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 964, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy


AWS Lambda was assigned a VPC and Security Group,
server parameter passed is an FQDN: hostname.domain.com - it is domain controller of AWS Directory Services
Following service role is applied:

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:xxx:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:xxx:log-group:/aws/lambda/Company_SSP:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

